# Setup Windows Azure Development Storage using a remote database

Tags: windows, azure, development-environment, azure-storage

I want to setup a Windows Azure development storage on my dev machine but I don't want to install SQL server on it because I want to use an existing one on another machine. Is it possible to set up the development storage service so that it uses the SQL server from another machine?

I tried calling dsinit with the /sqlinstance argument set to the remote machine, but it doesn't have any argument to allow me to specify the login credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the short answer is no.  Certainly dsinit is designed to only work on your local machine.

Can you setup the remote database server to use windows authentication and add the currently logged in user as an admin on that server?  That may be enough to fool it (but I wouldn't hold my breath)

If this doesn't work and you still don't want to SQL on your development machine, then using the actual Azure storage is not a bad idea.  It does cost some money, but not much and it does avoid some of the kinks that occur only in development storage.

Comment: Unfortunately, the long and short answers are both no. This is currently not supported. The best you could do was have a proxy installed locally and redirect everything to a remote server. But on the other hand, you don't need to have this on a remote server.

Answer (score 5):

You can use undocumented command line argument *`/server:`*.

Example: `dsinit /server:remote-sql-name`

---

> ```
> Added reservation for http://127.0.0.1:10000/ in user account DOMAIN\username.
> Added reservation for http://127.0.0.1:10001/ in user account DOMAIN\username.
> Added reservation for http://127.0.0.1:10002/ in user account DOMAIN\username.
>
> Creating database DevelopmentStorageDb20110816...
>
> Granting database access to user DOMAIN\username...
> The login already has an account under a different user name.
> Changed database context to 'DevelopmentStorageDb20110816'.
> Adding database role for user DOMAIN\username...
> User or role 'user' does not exist in this database.
> Changed database context to 'DevelopmentStorageDb20110816'.
>
> Initialization successful. The storage emulator is now ready for use.
> ```

Comment: We used this in our development environment and seems to be working fine.